AWS step function map task parameters values cannot be retrieved
This is part of my step function definition in the serverless yml.
CreateQuestions:
            Type: Map
            ItemsPath: "$.data.questions"
            Iterator:
              StartAt: CreateQuestion
              States:
                CreateQuestion:
                  Type: Task
                  Resource:
                    Fn::GetAtt: [createQuestion, Arn]
                  Parameters:
                    questionPath: "$"
                    projectId: "$.data.projectId"
                    isbn: "$.isbn"
                    packageId: "$.packageId"
                    jobId: "$.jobId"
                  End: true
            ResultPath: "$.resourceCreateResults"
            Next: CheckQuestionCreateStatus


and the event passed to CreateQuestions is below.
{
   "fileName":"1715254710431.zip",
   "filePath":"contents/source/dede7652-0cd5-4e19-8bf7-76ea853d3acc/1715254710431.zip",
   "isbn":"1715254710431",
   "packageType":"TEST",
   "packageId":"01J02HVK6QAAPGMN1CGK7T0R5C",
   "jobId":"dede7652-0cd5-4e19-8bf7-76ea853d3acc",
   "createdBy":"test@abc.com",
   "data":{
      "stepStatus":"SUCCEEDED",
      "projectId":"69cad2bc-d9ee-4d7d-8711-3dbb5c4bf060",
      "source":"ABC",
      "questions":[
         "questions/un02_as01_q111.xml",
         "questions/un03_as01_q111.xml"
      ]
   }
} 

Value for questionPath parameter comes properly iterating data.questions.
I am unable to get values for projectId, isbn, packageId and jobId parameter values from the original event. How to get those values?
Above description has details

You need to use the ItemSelector feature of the Step Functions Map State. This allows you to combine the item for your iteration (referenced as $$.Map.Item.Value) with other elements from the input to the Map state.
For example, you might add something like this.
ItemSelector:
  question.$: $$.Map.Item.Value
  projectId.$: $.data.projectId
  isbn.$: $.isbn
  packageId.$: $.packageId
  jobId.$: $.jobId
  


Thanks for the answer. Instead of ItemSelector, I used Parameters at the Map level and it worked.

Great. This is the same feature. Parameters is the deprecated original name and ItemSelector is the new field name.
